# Excel - How to combine a hyperlink cell and text cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My requirement is I have one cell with text and the next cell with a hyperlink. I need to add only the hyperlink to the text. Any ideas on how this can be achieved? I want to automate or use a formula so that it can be applied to all the 200 rows I have.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the formula

`=HYPERLINK(link_location;friendly_name)`

Example:

`=HYPERLINK(B1;A1)`

where B1 is the hyperlink cell and A1 is the name

Comment: Thanks, it work!